# A formal definition of circular proofs.

Tags: proof-theory

Suppose one were to prove that $\pi$ is irrational by claiming "because it is transcendental". This proof would be seen as circular. However, neither of "$\pi$ is irrational" and "$\pi$ is transcendental" is strictly stronger than the other, in fact, both are equally strong. So, what exactly is the formal definition of a circular proof?

Comment: I'd expect any proof involving $\pi$ to be circular. But what do you mean by saying "$\pi$ is irrational" and "$\pi$ is transcendental" are equally strong? In the sense that all true statements are equally strong, sure, but clearly "$x$ is transcendental" implies, and is not implied by, "$x$ is irrational".

Comment: If one has a proof that $\pi$ is transcendental that does not rely on knowing that $\pi$ is irrational, and if has shown that every transcendental number is irrational, then there is nothing in the least circular about the proposed argument, never mind that *$x$ is transcendental* **is** strictly stronger than *$x$ is irrational*.

Comment: Yes, "x is transcendental" is strictly stronger than "x is irrational". But "$\pi$ is transcendental" is equally as strong as "$\pi$ is irrational"

Comment: Because $\pi$ is a specific constant.

Comment: Are you familiar with the constant $\gamma$? It is a specific constant. Would you say "$\gamma$ is transcendental" is equally as strong as "$\gamma$ is irrational"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson That depends on whether it is transcendental or not.